# Does OS X have a setting that will let me apply a Gaussian Blur to the monitor or a specific window?

Tags: display

I've seen apps like [Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/) which allow one to focus or concentrate on the frontmost window by blurring out the others; I'm looking to do the opposite: blur out the main window (or the entire monitor) and be able to easily toggle it on or off.

My goal: using this with digital art software such as Photoshop or Illustrator, to create the "squint" effect one does to get a different perspective on how your artwork is progressing. I'd like to be able to toggle this on so I can work in "squint" mode for a bit, then toggle it off. Would be great to be able to easily set the blur level as well.

Hoping it can be accessed and toggled via Core Image and AppleScript or similar.

Comment: Why not just do this in Photoshop?

Comment: You could run something like Isolator and bring up a token front window (e.g. a TextEdit window, which can be made very small). That said, the fact that Isolator exists demonstrates that what you're looking for is *possible*. I don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: Isolator uses a desktop-sized window with specific properties: it will stay behind the "isolated" foreground window but above all other windows, it will be semi-transparent and it will blur its background. Maybe fooling around with window properties in XCode will reveal such settings?

Comment: @bassplayer7 - I need to to be a live effect that affects anything underneath it.

Comment: @fanaugen I don't have much familiarity with Xcode. But some of the research I did kept mentioning "gaussian blur" with "CoreImage" so it seemed a good place to start. I would have contact the Isolator developer but there is no contact info in the site.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do what you want, except recording it as a video and post-processing it, or writing the app yourself from scratch. Perhaps you could send an email to omnigroup, asking if they could add that feature to omnidazzle? If you're going to create it yourself in Xcode, you should ask on stack overflow. You want a full screen borderless window above all other windows, with a blurred effect, and all mouse clicks going through it.

Answer (score 6):

**Warning: this is a workaround.**

Terminal.app lets you set the exact settings of its window. If you set them correctly, you can get a transparent window with a gaussian blur. If you simply leave a window open in the background in Terminal while doing your work, then bring up Terminal when you want to, this *should* work great. You can even make the text transparent if you want.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This will do the trick as a workaround, thank you! Not sure if I should mark as answered or not, but for my needs this suffices.

Comment: @GeorgeC Of course I wouldn't mind if you accepted it, but considering that it's a workaround maybe it would be best to leave it as unanswered for the nonce.